# Do not stretch part of drawable

Tags: android, user-interface, drawable

I need to make `ticket` view which consists of the left and right part.
[image]

I would like to make the right area with `QR` code not stretchable by width. In other words, the right part should always be equal despite screen size. The left part should match all allowed size.
Is there any way to do this manipulation with drawable?
Note: I have an idea how to do this with two layouts and two backgrounds, but this is a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

```
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                      <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/etItemName"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:hint="@string/str_item_name"/>

                         <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/etItemName"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:hint="@string/str_item_name"/>
                       </LinearLayout>

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/ivCamera"
                                android:layout_width="100dp"
                                android:layout_height="100dp"
                                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                               app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_vector_camera_solid_gray" />
                        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                    </LinearLayout>
```